# javascript Unexpected token *

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get an integer from a JSON and multiply it with a number that has an exponentiation. However, it gives me

> let dec = 10 ** _decimals;
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

The code is the following:

```
let dec = 10 ** _decimals;
let value = parseInt(req.body.burn_value) * dec;
```

I can't figure out why it is doing that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `**` is not multiplication -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation

Comment: You could use `Math.pow`, for example; `Math.pow(10, _decimals)`

Comment: Can't see any JSON here, `let dec = 10 ** _decimals;` looks like JavaScript.

Comment: also [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Too tired to write properly :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your environment doesn't support the new-ish exponentiation operator. But if you're just trying to multiply it, use `*` instead:

```
let dec = 10 * _decimals;
```

Or if you are trying to use exponentiation:

```
let dec = Math.pow(10, _decimals);
```

Comment: The ** is a 'to the power of' operator, so 10 ** 2 is 100, not 20.

Comment: Now your args are the wrong way around in the `Math.pow`